# Getting wordpress to ignore folder as theme

Tags: php, wordpress

At the moment i'm making a new wordpress site, and i'm using the following plugin

[Wordpress Multiple Theme Plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/)

To have 2 themes on my site. I want a front end and a system/dashboard backend. Thats working great.

I am developing using grunt as my task runner, and I have set up my grunt file with Browsersync, sass, babel etc to look at both front and back end folders, so my folder structure looks like this

```
wp-content/themes
|
| --- Front End Theme
| --- Back End Theme
| --- node_modules
| --- package.json
| --- gruntfile.js
```

But because wordpress can see the node_modules folder, i'm currently getting the following wordpress error on my appearance/themes page

```
Broken Themes
The following themes are installed but incomplete.

Name    Description     
node_modules    Stylesheet is missing.
```

Is there any way I can get wordpress to ignore the `node_modules` folder so that my error disappears?

Comment: Toss an empty style.css file into your node_modules directory. That *shouldn't* mess with grunt.

Comment: @disinfor but wont I have to add the style.css file back in every time run an npm command?

Comment: Your grunt task runners shouldn't be rebuilding your `node_modules` directory and dependencies every time you run a command.

Comment: I know, I said an `npm` command not grunt, like adding a new dependency.

Comment: Have you tried it? I'm curious how often you would be adding a new dependency.

Comment: Doesn't work, just changes the error to `Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet.`

Comment: Yeah, you need to add the template markup inside of the style.css. It's not just a blank file. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ Try faking a child theme in the node_modules folder. Check out step #2 from that link and add that markup to your style.css.

Comment: Its ok, I don't think this is the method i'm looking for. This will make the node modules show up in my application themes, I dont want it to show up, I want it to disappear all together from the theme selection screen.

Comment: Then you may have to move your node_modules directory to another location. Good luck!